# WebStorm support for postcss-simple-vars

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, postcss

How can I make WebStorm support the following PostCSS syntax.

[image]

Could it be solved by adding plugin path into Stylesheets => Dialects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not yet supported.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24368 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.